# Using python to take the time difference from a previous non-NaN reading

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
b = []
if (df['Temperature'].notna()).any() is True: 
   b = df['unixTime'].diff()
b
```

I am attempting to take the unix time difference from the last time there was a temperature reading. I am attempting to create the time difference column that I have shown in the picture in python. The current code I have does not work because it takes the time difference from the previous unix time and not the previous unix time that there was a temperature reading. Any suggestions?
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISfCx.png)

Comment: When you get a valid temperature reading, save last recorded time value and when you get a new reading, compute difference between current time and last recorded time.  Then update last recorded time for the next reading

Comment: Please provide your input data as DataFrame constructor, not image

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but `x.any() is True` could maybe be shortened to just `x.any()`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['time_difference'] = df.dropna(subset='Temperature')['unixTime'].diff()
```